# How to pass a two dimensional list/array between groovy scripts in soap ui?

Tags: arrays, list, soap, multidimensional-array, groovy

Problem statement: We need a way to pass a two dimensional list (or array) from one groovy script to other scripts ( to assert values from multiple DB2 tables in other scripts].

Some Background: 
Step1: Based on our input xml payload we are capturing the list of nodes (and child elements) in a two dimensional list [][]. [Done] 
Step2: Now we want to use the values from each of this list to assert with respect to values in DB2 tables [Also done, however keeping both step1 and step2 in same groovy script].

What we want is to to be able to pass the 2dimensional list from step1 in step2. Specially important since we have multiple tables and we dont want to either add all table steps in one big groovy script Or to duplicate step1 code in each Db2 validataion script.

We read about setting each element value from list at test case level and then reconstructing the array back but we are hesitating to use that method due to (varying &) huge size of list elements (in thousands). Question is: Are there any clean ways to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `context`

That's real working `Groovy Script` steps.

step1:

```
def array = ['Kyiv', 'Boryspil', 'Kharkiv', "L'Viv", "Odesa"]
context.setProperty('cities', array)
log.info( 'script1: '+array )
```

step2:

```
def array = context.getProperty('cities')
log.info( 'script2: '+array )
assert array.size()>0
```

> Note:
>
> If you run just one step, then there will be absolutely
>   independent context.
>
> But if you run the whole testcase then there will be context shared
>   for the whole testcase.
>
> You can use `Run from here` context menu in your test case window to run from exact step.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this doesn't work when in context we use context.testcase.setpropertyValue('Myarray',inputarray) and try to call it using getpropertyvalue in another groovy script. Will only work in same script. 
Can you share an example with two scripts setting and getting the values? Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! This explains. Thanks a lot for your time and helping me out on this. I found another method yesterday using creating StringToObject map, but your method is much more cleaner. I dont have enough points to do a thumbs up on your answer, but here I say it " Thumbs up" for your help :).

Answer (score 1):

As you are aware of the limitation of the earlier solution, which would only work (sharing of object between the groovy scripts) if the test case is run and does not work if individual steps are run.

Here I want to provide an approach which over comes that by using groovy's meta programming.

**In script 1**, have the below code:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase

WsdlTestCase.metaClass.myList = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

**In script 2**, have the below code:

```
log.info "From script 2: ${context.testCase.myList}"
assert [1,2,3,4,5] == context.testCase.myList
```

The above even works if individual steps are run.
Hope this is helpful.

EDIT: come to understand that user required to update the list repeatedly and with metaClass user couldn't update the list. Here is the alternative:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase
WsdlTestCase.metaClass.myObject = new Expando(myList: [1,2,3,4,5])
log.info "list initialized: ${context.testCase.myObject.myList}"
WsdlTestCase.metaClass.myObject = new Expando(myList: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
log.info "list updated: ${context.testCase.myObject.myList}"
```

Comment: Thanks for adding your response @Rao. This helps!

Comment: May I ask you in which version of SoapUI you tested it?I am trying to get this in 5.4 and it doesn't override the property even in 1 script.
I run it and only 1-5 is printed to log in both cases. I can't get the 1-7 even in 1 script, not talking about using it in other script (only first write is returned).
Also, to clear the value of the property I have to restart SoapUI, if I assign empty array [] it doesn't work as well.

Comment: May be tried on 4.5.x. But that should not be really matter I believe. Would you please provide the sample project to reproduce the same?