# Pass dynamic response to Groovy Script Test step as String parameter

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I am trying to pass `json` response to Groovy 'jsonString' parameter. It is correctly working when I pass json manually in code. But my response is dynamic and i need to pass at runtime.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
String jsonString = context.expand('${REST SearchRooms#Response}')
JsonSlurper jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
Map convertedJSONMap  = jsonSlurper.parseText(jsonString)
if(convertedJSONMap."RoomSearchResult")
{
    log.info "ResourceItemID : " + convertedJSONMap."RoomSearchResult"[0]."ResourceItemID"
}
```

My json response look like this :

```
{
   "Success": true,
   "TotalRecords": 2,
   "RoomSearchResult":    [
            {
         "ResourceItemID": 2290,
         "Name": "Room 23 (L02)",
         "LocationId": 7,
         "GroupID": 518,
         "FloorID": 2,
         "DefaultCapacity": 4,
         "CanBeBooked": true
      },
{
         "ResourceItemID": 2063,
         "Name": "Room 15 (L10)",
         "LocationId": 7,
         "GroupID": 518,
         "FloorID": 10,
         "DefaultCapacity": 8,
         "CanBeBooked": true
      }
   ],
   "Error":    {
      "ErrorCode": 0,
      "ErrorDescription": ""
   }
}
```

Error : The JSON input text should neither be null nor empty.

I am new to groovy. Please suggest how to do it.

Comment: the question is similar ti this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44421624/how-to-pass-a-two-dimensional-list-array-between-groovy-scripts-in-soap-ui/44422551#44422551

Comment: Is your previous step name, `REST Test Request`, correct?

Comment: I updated the question with exact test step i used and error message. 'SearchRooms' is my current test step. Which response i want to pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have trivial error.

Chage below line

**From:**

```
String jsonString = context.expand('${REST SearchRooms#Response}')
```

**To:**

```
String jsonString = context.expand('${SearchRooms#Response}')
```